# Counting Donut Problem

Tags: combinatorics

> We are going to select $12$ donuts from among sprinkles, caramel, chocolate, and maple (all equally likely). What is the probability that we select exactly $3$ maple and $1 $ chocolate donuts?

This means that there are three partitions, so total number of spots would be $15.$ I then figure that ${15\choose 12}$ would give all possible combinations but how do I get to the point of $3$ maple and 1 chocolate?

Final ans given: $9/455$

Comment: I think all possible combinations would be $4^{12}$

Comment: It would be C(15,12) because you have 15 spots-including those for partitions-and you need to select 12. I only know this because this was a point my professor went over multiple times. However, I can't figure out the next steps.

Comment: If we assume all the sprinkles are selected first, then the caramel, chocolate, and maple in that order, then it's $C(15,12)$. But if each doughnut choice can be anything, then it is $4^{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that we select the doughnuts one at a time, and that the  $4^{12}$ possible sequences of choices are all  *equally likely*.

The number of *favourable* sequences is $\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{1}2^{8}$. For we are counting the $12$-letter words  in a $4$-letter alphabet A, B, C, D that have $3$ A's and $1$ B. The locations of the A's can be chosen in $\binom{12}{3}$ ways, and for each way the location of the B can be chosen in $\binom{9}{1}$ ways. The remaining $8$ spots can be filled with C's and/or D's in $2^8$ ways.

For the probability, divide the number of favourables by the total number of possibilities.

**Remark:** I prefer the following approach. Any *particular* sequence that has $3$ maple (it really should be "maple," as in oil-derived artificial maple, perhaps heavy oil, to give it a Canadian flavour), $1$ chocolate, and $8$ other has probability $(1/4)^3(1/4)^1(2/4)^8$, and there are $\binom{12}{3,1,8}$ (multinomial coefficient) such sequences. So the probability is $\binom{12}{3,1,8}(1/4)^3(1/4)^1(2/4)^8$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you are selecting a grand total of 12 donuts.

The total permutations (where order matters) for your choices number 4^12.

Also consider: Since picking any given flavor is exactly as likely as picking any other, all possible overall **permutations** occur with the same probability.

However, what you are looking for is a bit more specific. You want, in your selection, to have 3 maples and 1 chocolate, precisely! The rest of the choices can be any combination of caramel and sprinkles. So how many ways can this occur?

Well you have 12 objects, 3 identical (maples), 1 specified (chocolate), and 8 that can be as they please from 2 options.

So we have the multinomial $12!/3!1!8! that represents the number of arrangements for 3 maples, 1 chocolate and 8 "abstract scoops". However, these "abstract scoops", when counting permutations, account for many different scoop selections, in fact there will be 2^8 different selections (where order counts). For the maples and chocolate, well there is only one way you can pick 3 maples and 1 chocolate, precisely by picking, so 1 (or 1^1*1^3 if you want to be very rigorous :) ).

So the total number of permutations for what you want is: $(12!/(3!*1!*8!))*2^8$

So the probability that you will get such a permutation is the quotient of that and 4^12

If you aren't sure about the above, check each individual case, where your constants are 1 chocolate scoop and 3 maples scoops. So a given scenario to check would be:

1 choc, 3 maple, 1 vanilla, 7 caramel or $12!/1!3!1!7!$

You will find that it all sums to (12!/(3!*1!*8!))*2^8$

This beautiful property is due to the nice identity:

$$2^n = n!/0!n! + n!/1!(n-1)! + n!/2!(n-2)! + n!/3!(n-3)! + … + n!/n!(n-n)!$$

I.e. a row in pascal's triangle is equal to 2^(number of the row).

Answer (score 0):

We make the assumption that all unordered selections of 12 doughnuts are equally likely (so that, for example, choosing 12 maple is just as likely as choosing 4 maple, 4 chocolate, and 4 caramel).

If we choose exactly 3 maple and 1 chocolate, then there are only 9 ways to select the other 8 doughnuts since the number n of possibilities for the caramel satisfies $0\le n\le8$

(or using $\binom{9}{1}$, since there are 8 doughnuts and one divider needed).

The total number of ways to choose the 12 doughnuts is given by $\binom{15}{12}=\binom{15}{3}=455$, since this is equal to the number of ways to arrange 12 dots and 3 dividers.

Therefore the probability (under the assumption stated above) is given by $\frac{9}{455}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the number of ways to arrange the letters MMMCOOOOOOOO, $12!/\left(3!1!8!\right)$, where M=Maple, C=Chocolate and O=Other and each selection has a probability of P(M) = P(C) = 1/4 and P(O) = 1/2 so for any particular arrangement the probability is $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{8}$. The total probability is just the product.